# Target to a page inside an iframe

Tags: html, iframe

I will try to explain again:

I have 3 images in my index.html that when clicked i'd like to point respectively to ourmission.html, ourvalues.html and ourvision.html.
But this 3 pages are inside an iframe located in the page ourcompany.html as you can see below:

```
<aside class="sidebar">
<h4>Our Company</h4>
    <ul class="nav nav-list primary pull-bottom">
        <li><a href="contactus.html"target="conteudo">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="ourmission.html" target="conteudo">Our Mission</a></li>
        <li><a href="ourvalues.html" target="conteudo">Our Values</a></li>
        <li><a href="ourvision.html"target="conteudo">Our Vision</a></li>

</ul>
</aside>

<iframe src="contactus.html" frameborder='0' name="conteudo" width="700" height="700">
</iframe>
```

How do i to point them directly, so the page ourcompany.html will load with the specific iframe opened.

Comment: can you edit the pages inside the iframes that you have?

Comment: Yeah. I can edit all the pages if it is needed.

Comment: What do you mean by "target" it to the iframe?

Comment: If I use the target="iframe" I can point to the iframe but it will open its default page. But what I need to do is open directly the other pages inside the iframe instead of its default. Each item in page A will link directly to one of the iframe pages in page B.

Comment: so dont target it to its default page, target it to the other page. 

This is what I understand. YOu have `pageA.html`, `pageB.html` and `pageC.html`. Right now you have `pageA.html` with an iframe which has `target="pageB.html"` but you want to see `pageC.html`. So what you need to do is `target ="pageC.html"` and that should show you that page.

Comment: No. In my pageA.html I have an icon that I want to point to pageC.html. And pageC.html is inside an iframe in pageB.html.

Comment: so you want an icon in `pageA.html` to be shown in `pageC.html`? Could you also post the code for page A, B and C, because I still dont understand you

Comment: Added code to the question to clarify!

Comment: Do you have a server setup to work with the website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the solution adding the following code to the page where the iframe is located:

```
<script>
window.onload = function loadIframe(){ 
if (location.search.length > 0){ 
url = unescape(location.search.substring(1))

window.frames["iframe-name"].location=url 
} 
} 
</script>
```

and using the href as:

```
<a href="iframe-page.html?specific-iframe.html">
```

Thanks a lot for everyone that tried to help me.

Answer (score 2):

This might be a possible solution for you, if I have understood you correctly.
I am assuming you dont have a server set up with the website.

In your index.html, your image links need to be modified to this:

```
<a href="ourcompany.html?link=ourmission"><img src="" /></a> 
<a href="ourcompany.html?link=ourvalues"><img src="" /></a> 
<a href="ourcompany.html?link=ourvision"><img src="" /></a>
```

Notice the `?link=someValue` after the ourcompany.html link. This is a GET request but you will use it to pass data between pages.

Now in your `ourcompany.html` page you need to get the value you sent after the `?link=`. So you  need to add some Javascript. This is the function you need to add to ourcompany.html:

```
function getValue()
{
  // First, we load the URL into a variable
  var url = window.location.href;

  // Next, split the url by the ?
  var qparts = url.split("?");

  // Check that there is a querystring, return "" if not
  if (qparts.length == 0)
  {
    return "";
  }

  // Then find the querystring, everything after the ?
  var query = qparts[1];

  // Initialize the value with "" as default
  var value = "";

   var parts = query.split("=");

   // Load value into variable
   value = parts[1];

  // Convert escape code
  value = unescape(value);

  // Return the value
  return value;
}
```

Now you can change the iframe `src` attribute accordingly like this:

```
var link = getValue();
if (link.length){//check if you got a value
    document.getElementByName('conteudo').src = link + ".html";//set the src
}
```

Comment: It didn't work. Showed the correct address (ie: `ourcompany.html?link=ourmission`)  in address bar but still loading the default iframe.